# Django view do nothing on form submit

Tags: django, forms

I have a form whose submit should only be handled once.

Any extra clicks on the submit button should do nothing, where nothing means also not interrupting the flow of the first submit's POST request, which redirects to a GET when it finishes.

What (if anything) can I return from Django's `View`'s `post` method to achieve this behavior? Returning an empty `HttpResponse` as suggested in some other related questions on SO seems to interrupt the browser and display an empty page, thus interrupting the GET redirect which I'd like the browser to wait for.

Looking for a server-side solution here, not just javascript disable of the submit button.

Also, I can't just redirect the user to the GET page immediately on the second submit, since the page shows a success status and I'm only interested in showing that once the handling of the first POST is complete, which may take a few seconds.

Comment: Have you considered using a `StreamingHttpResponse`? You could initialize the response with a generator that performs your logic and then return the response immediately

Comment: Why not disable the button with JS? Most "double clicks" happen accidentally as double clicks, so waiting even for a direct server response would already take too long time.

Comment: @C14L I'm for disabling the button with JS, but looking for a robust solution which would work for a) disabled javascript b) quick double-clicks which may happen if the JS didn't run fast enough.

Comment: @IainShelvington Not sure I got the idea; even if I return a StreamingHttpResponse, there's nothing preventing the user from re-submitting the form while the response is loading.

Comment: @Danra Without JS you can't disable the button onclick, because you can't remember the state. Another way would be to use a unique ID for each form served. Then on submit, check if a form with that unique ID had already been submitted and only accept the first submit. But that would only be useful if the form creates a new object. A form that updates an existing object should be okay with repeated requests.